# Re-use a component that includes a context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a complex component that uses a context internally. For example:

```
// ComplexComponent.tsx

const MyContext = createContext({});
export function useMyContext() {
  return useContext(MyContext);
}

export default function ComplexComponent({ fooValue }) {
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ foo: fooValue }}>
      <NestedComponent />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

```
// NestedComponent.tsx

import { useMyContext } from './ComplexComponent';

export default function NestedComponent() {
  const { foo } = useMyContext();
  return (
    <div>
      { foo }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there a way to generate context(s) dynamically, so that I can re-use this component in other places in the code (while a few instances occur simultaneously)?

Obviously I'd have to put the `createContext` function *inside* `ComplexComponent`, but then I won't be able to import `useMyContext`.

Comment: Can you show an example of such "reuse", what the generic use here? Do you mean you want some ability to dynamically create custom hooks (like `useContext`)? So you can't. If you meaning in just creating context, so you can have a HOC.

Comment: Ofc you can write some kind of generator (which will return a custom hook given an instance name), but it's a very uncommon pattern... Won't recommend

Comment: Thank you, @DennisVash. I have a complex dropdown, which I want to re-use simply with different data (like I used `fooValue` in my example)

Comment: You want to create new context per new data? Please show an example in the question itself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As React's context is global, I didn't want to even go in the direction of generating contexts dynamically.

I ended up using a simple state inside `ComplexComponent`, as it's well encapsulated and allow using as many independent instances of `ComplexComponent` as I want.

However, this solution has the obvious downside of passing the "context params" down each level of children components.

Answer (score 0):

From the `Context` [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context):

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components

From what I understand your problem is, I don't think React `Context` supports what you want to achieve.

As a potential alternative, you could define a setter function that could be called from your nested components, however:

```js
// ComplexComponent.tsx

// ...

export default function ComplexComponent({ fooValue }) {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(fooValue);
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ foo, setFoo }}>
      <NestedComponent />
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

And then set it "dynamically" like so:

```js
// NestedComponent.tsx

// ...

export default function NestedComponent() {
  const { foo, setFoo } = useMyContext();
  setFoo("New Foo Value");
  return (
    <div>
      { foo }
    </div>
  );
}
```

The caveat here is that this will update the value of `foo` in every consumer of your context. I would argue that if you want to have different components with different values of `foo`, you'd be better off just passing `fooValue`'s to them as `props`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However your solution still doesn't allow multiple instances of `ComplexComponent`, as any update would affect all the instances

Comment: Right, it sounds like the most straightforward path for you might be to just to create two separate contexts, unfortunately.